# Phonegap insert query + not working

Tags: ios, sqlite, cordova

I am using phoneagap framework for APP development.
Insert query in phonegap:

```
tx.executeSql('insert into "'+gAppConfig.configTable+'" (key , value) values(uniqueId,"'+uniqueId+'"),(serverURL,"'+serverURL+'")' , querySuccess, errorQuery);
```

This is not working, Can anybody tell me what could be wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you've created a table in the database, and you've named it "tablename" with 2 columns "id" & "serverURL"; where "id" is the primary key.

Try this:

```
   Iquery = "INSERT INTO 'tableName' VALUES(null, "+serverURL+");";
   tx.executeSql(
      Iquery,
      null,
      function(){ /* to do on success, or you may just set it as "null" */},
      function(){ /* to do on error, or you may just set it as "null" */});
```

or you may try this:

```
 tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO tableName(id, serverURL) VALUES (?,?)",
        [null, serverURL], // these are the variables to insert
        function(){ /* to do on success, or you may just set it as "null" */},
        function(){ /* to do on fail, or you may just set it as "null" */});
```

you may refer to the original [documentation of cordova](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#SQLTransaction) for more info.